# OpenGL - Instanced font rendering vs rendering char by char

Tags: java, opengl

I wanted to implement font-rendering with OpenGL in Java.
This post mainly focuses on the speed of the rendering process.

I know that usually you would try to reduce the amount of render-calls so rendering char by char is not as efficient as instanced font rendering would be.

But let's say I've got 300 chars. Would it take to long to render char by char?

Comment: There are probably a million ways to render a font. Bitmap? Mesh? Render text to bitmap and upload as texture? Render glyphs to texture and draw as many quads? Lots of rendering calls seem unusual.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I think using a bitmap would be the easiest thing for me to do. Then rendering a quad multiple times. Giving the texture-coords as a uniform variable

Comment: Texture coords as uniform variables would be very unusual. Usually they are attributes, specified with the vertex data. You can render an entire piece of text to a texture, or you can render all your glyphs to a texture and render quads from there.

Comment: Starting out, the easiest thing is to just render all of your text to a texture and then render that as a single quad. This doesn't require much code and it's fast.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Is that something that I might do fully in Java or should I use the GPU for that? I mean I could "bake" a texture on the CPU if that's what you mean

Comment: I am not sure what "bake" means. You can use a library like FreeType to render text to a bitmap image. FreeType has Java bindings. You then upload the bitmap as an OpenGL texture so you can draw it to the screen.